# How do I set maximum margin-top in jquery animation?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code in jQuery, that animates a div marginTop.

How do I set it so that once the margin top is equal 900px, disable the click event?

```
$("#tmbUp").click(function(){ 
$("#tmbHolder").animate({"marginTop": "-=100px"}, "slow");
});

$("#tmbDown").click(function(){
$("#tmbHolder").animate({"marginTop": "+=100px"}, "slow");
});
```

Comment: check `bind/unbind` jquery methods

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before you call the `animate` function, simply check the current value of the top margin.  If it's 900 (or less), don't animate.

Answer (score 1):

The `animate` method has the option to take a callback function.

What you want to do is something like this:

```
$("#tmbDown").click (function (){ 
  $("#tmbHolder").animate (
    {"marginTop": "+=100px"}, 
    "slow",
    "swing",
    // The callback function
    function () {
      if ($(this).css ('marginTop') >= "900px") {
        $("#tmbDown").unbind ('click');
      }
    }
  );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you want to disable the click event only when the marginTop is >= 900, and enable it again when/if the user reduces the marginTop. I suggest taking advantage of the callback function that is built into the animate function.

```
$("#tmbUp").click(function(){ 
    $("#tmbHolder").animate({"marginTop": "-=100px"}, "slow", 
        function() {
            // if tmbHolder's marginTop < 900px, enable #tmbDown
        }
    );
});

$("#tmbDown").click(function(){
    $("#tmbHolder").animate({"marginTop": "+=100px"}, "slow", 
        function() {
            // if tmbHolder's marginTop >= 900px, disable #tmbDown
        }
    );
});
```

Hope that does it for you.